# Declarative schema definition with Diesel

Tags: mysql, rust, rdbms, ddl, rust-diesel

I want to write table schemas declarative way like

- GORM AutoMigrate https://gorm.io/ko_KR/docs/migration.html
- django Migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/

However, As far I know, Diesel requires hand-written migration DDL like below.

```sql
-- up.sql
CREATE TABLE members (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
-- down.sql
DROP TABLE members;
```

It is complex a little bit because it is stateful.

Is a declarative way to write schemas provided by Diesel?
Or do a good external tool exist?

I found Prisma can generate DDL equivalent to up.sql from declarative schema written in its own syntax.
But I couldn't find a way to generate down.sql
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to keep your rust entities and db schema in sync, without having to write any SQL (which is basically what a regular orm like EFCore or GORM would provide).

If that's what you need, I'm afraid diesel won't do what you're looking for.
There is this library which looks nice https://github.com/rust-db/barrel, and it provides a way for you to write your migrations in Rust instead of SQL, a bit like EFCore.

diesel also provides the `embed_migrations!` macro, which you can use in order to automatically run migrations without using the cli.

However, while all these tools will sort of help you out in automating your db migrations, you're still going to have to write them manually.

Comment: Thank you, I think you understand correctly (I'm sorry for my poor English).
For more details, what I don't want to write is not SQL.
I don't want to write "How to migrate tables".
But I'm Okay to write "What is the latest schema".

barrel is good to know, but it seems not to solve the problem.
I'm still going to write "How to migrate" manually as you wrote.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there's no way of achieving what you're talking about in Rust. I run a startup where the whole code base is written in Rust, and we too were looking for some tools to automate migrations away, but unfortunately we couldn't find any.

Comment: We're in the process of deciding whether writing a tool ourselves would be worth it , and if we end up doing that I'll definitely keep you posted.

Comment: I'm looking forward to hear the tool.